# Displaying a PDF from a URL in Nativescript

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I'm trying to display a PDF from a url using a webview. I've tried loading it using the src attribute and the url attribute. I've also attempted to load it from the onLoaded event in Javascript, but still no luck...Is there a better way to load a PDF doc in a Nativescript app? The webview loads something small like the google url with out any issues. Here's some of the code I've tried.

```
// did not work 
<WebView row="0" id="eula-view" src="https://somewebsite/eula/foo.pdf"/>

// did not work 
<WebView row="0" id="eula-view" url="https://somewebsite/eula/foo.pdf" />

//worked fine 
<WebView row="0" id="eula-view" url="http://google.com" />
```

Loading from JS rather than from xml

```
//did not work 
exports.viewLoaded = function (args) {    
    var page = args.object;
    var webview = page.getViewById("eula-view");
    webview.url = "https://somewebsite/eula/foo.pdf"; 
}; 

// worked fine
exports.viewLoaded = function (args) {    
    var page = args.object;
    var webview = page.getViewById("eula-view");
    webview.url = "http://google.com"; 
};
```

Comment: The working url is http, the not working https, maybe you have to setup the ssl?

Comment: Unfortunately that did not make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a NativeScript plugin for displaying PDF files on iOS and Android. I haven't personally tried the `WebView` approach with Google Docs, because I need to display PDF files from the local device, and don't want to require an active Internet connection.

The plugin is [`nativescript-pdf-view`](https://github.com/Merott/nativescript-pdf-view). Usage is like this:

**Plain NativeScript:**

```
<Page
 xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded"
 xmlns:pdf="nativescript-pdf-view">
  <StackLayout>
    <pdf:PDFView src="{{ pdfSrc }}"/>
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

**Angular 2**

```
// somewhere in the JavaScript/TypeScript:
import 'nativescript-pdf-view';

// in the view:
<PDFView [src]="pdfSrc"></PDFView>
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much for posting this! Can the PDF src still be a url? Or does it have to be local to the device?

Comment: I just verfied in your code that url source will work. I've marked this as the answer, as I feel it's a better implementation. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. If you find any issues feel free to let me know on Github, or better yet, make PRs! :)